# How to find out what Ruby version a project has used + Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rbenv

I cloned one of my 3years old project from Github to resurrect, however I'm getting bunch of migrations, gem, etc errors. Googling gives me tips about possibly using wrong ruby version.

I want to assign the specific `rbenv local rubyver` but I don't know which one I used and I can't find it in any settings?

Any idea how I can find what Ruby version is this project using?

Comment: Sometimes there's a line in the Gemfile which mentions it. Or there might be a .ruby-version file.You could also check the history of Ruby releases to line up which one was stable 3 years ago

Comment: End of 2017 Ruby 2.5 was released at the same time the 2.2 - 2.4 versions were still maintained and got updated on a regular basis. When the project is about three years old then I would guess that the developers at the time used the latest stable version to start the new project. That means my best guess is: Ruby 2.4. But because 2.4 coursed trouble the might have still used 2.3.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few places this *might* be annotated:

1. A `.ruby-version` file, though these are often ignored to avoid friction between developers with slightly different versions. This is what `rbenv` uses, as well as other tools like RVM.
2. The `Gemfile` can have a `ruby` version lock in it, though this is usually a *minimum* requirement, like `>= 2.3.0`.
3. The `README` if the developer is kind.

Otherwise, there's no real way to know.

It's worth noting that Ruby 2.0, 2.4 and 3.0 are often the biggest upgrade hurdles, so it's worth trying with the latest version you can get away with, like 2.7.2 if practical, 3.0.0 if possible.

Comment: The fact that this is tagged with [tag:ruby-on-rails] makes these hurdles even greater given the fact that one will likely have to upgrade rails as well.